# I am a German citizen living in the UK. Will I have health insurance while visiting Germany?

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, health-insurance, german-citizens, health-system

I am a German citizes living in the UK, I am registered with the NHS and have no further health insurance in Germany. I will visit Germany multiple times over the next months, and I wonder whether I will be insured in any way?

GOV.UK's advice to its nationals is to apply for a EHIC/GHIC card, but I cannot do this at this moment because I do not yet posess a National Insurance Number (I have applied for one, but this can take up to 14 weeks, and I will visit Germany regularly in this time).

This scares me quite a bit, since it seems like I have no insurance whatsoever. Germany is usually rather cautious that everyone inside its borders has some form of health insurance. So, does Germany have some measures in place for "tourists"? Or will I have to pay upfront but will be reimbursed by the NHS? Or am I indeed completely uninsured?

Comment: Do you have travel insurance?

Comment: @Traveller No, I hoped that there are better fitting solutions for my circumstances. I am not traveling to a foreign country, but to a country that I am a citizen of. I am not afraid of getting robbed or having problems with my accomodation as I will live basically at home I and know the neighborhood and everything. I am not on vacation, not planning any risky hiking trips, no skiing or diving etc. But if this is the only option I am left with, I will have to look at that.

Comment: "I am not traveling to a foreign country, but to a country that I am a citizen of": you are traveling to a country where you do not reside and have no insurance coverage.  When a UK insurer offers insurance for travel to "a foreign country," it means "a country other than the UK," not "a country where the insured party is a foreigner."

Comment: Look into travel insurance (health only).  Health coverage for a one week trip from UK to Germany is about $20 and that includes Covid medical coverage. It's quick and cheap and MUCH easier than trying to navigate national health care plans and cross-country insurance politics.

Comment: Your update would qualify as an answer, that you could then accept (since there are no other answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is what I did in the end**

I decided for a so-called "in-coming" insurance, which is offered by some German insurance providers and is specifically designed for foreigners visiting Germany for a short time. It seems to be largely equivalent to a travel insurance which you have to buy in your country of residence. However, for me the "in-coming" insurance had the following advantages:

- one can choose to have health insurance only (I do not need the other services of a travel insurance).
- specifically designed for the German health care system.
- restricted to Germany only (I do not need insurance in other parts of the EU or Schengen area etc.).
- everything is in German (which is my mother tongue).

It was around 50€ for a month.